# Ansible bash profile, prevent verbosity

Tags: shell, command-line, terminal, ansible

I'm installing [Ansible](http://ansible.cc/), and have added the commands below to my `~/.bash_profile` file.

```
# Setup Ansible
cd ~/github/ansible
source ./hacking/env-setup
cd ~
export ANSIBLE_HOSTS=~/ansible_hosts
# End Ansible Setup
```

Now every time I open a new Terminal window, it logs the message below.

> Setting up Ansible to run out of checkout...
>
> PATH=/github/ansible/bin:/Users/.../.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin:/Users/.../.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@global/bin:/Users/.../.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin:/Users/.../.rvm/bin:/Users/.../sbt/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin
>   PYTHONPATH=/Users/.../Documents/Projects/eclipse-workspace/ansible/ansible/lib:
>   ANSIBLE_LIBRARY=/Users/.../Documents/Projects/eclipse-workspace/ansible/ansible/library
>   MANPATH=/Users/.../Documents/Projects/eclipse-workspace/ansible/ansible/docs/man:
>
> Remember, you may wish to specify your host file with -i
>
> Done!

How can I prevent the Terminal from logging these messages?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can change the bash profile to read like this instead:

```
cd ~/github/ansible
source ./hacking/env-setup >& /dev/null
cd ~
```

Or just:

```
source ~/github/ansible/hacking/env-setup >& /dev/null
```

This will just redirect standard output and error to /dev/null, silencing the messages.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I would recommend to use the built-in -q argument like this `. ~/github/ansible/hacking/env-setup -q`